# A rod is attached to a star in a galaxy at the edge of the observable universe and it reaches earth. Will that rod start moving faster than light?

Tags: cosmology, faster-than-light

It is known that the galaxies at the edge of the observable universe are accelerating away from us and eventually they will start moving faster than light with respect to our frame. However, suppose that just before such a galaxy sped to past the speed of light, one attached a long rod to a star in that galaxy and the other end of that rod reaches a point close to earth, and an observer is placed close to that other end of the rod. Will that observer eventually see that end of the rod traveling faster than light? We presume that the rod is rigid and is not massive enough to affect the speed of the star it is attached to. We also presume that no bodies close to that rod are significantly affecting its motion via gravity or are bumping into it.

Comment: this kind of question must be the most asked in the history of physics. If you google "rigid rod speed of light" you will find a plethora of related questions with explanations

Answer (score 4):

> We presume that the rod is rigid

You cannot presume that the rod is rigid. Rigid objects are incompatible with relativity and the known laws of physics.

Upon removing the un-physical presumption, what happens is simply that the rod stretches and possibly breaks, depending on the material characteristics.

Comment: Assuming that the rod isn't rigid and is deformable/breakable, at what point does the rod break and at what time? Because I don't see any single point in the rod where the tension force starts tending to infinity or any other oddities like that. The only way I see that the rod will break is if the same force (dark force?) that's accelerating the galaxies further away from Earth also acts on the rod uniformly along its length, thus stretching it to the point of breaking. However I don't know much about dark force and could be wrong.

Comment: @TheTestosteroneFanatic, yes, the force stretching the rod is from dark energy. The situation is more complicated than this answer suggests. If there's no dark energy then a rod attached to a distant object can in principle avoid breaking forever, even if the recessional speed of the object it's attached to is greater than $c$. In the zero-matter limit, it can even be rigid. Its local speed in that case is $c\tanh(v/c)$ where $v$ is the recessional speed. Recessional speeds in general are somewhat like special-relativistic [rapidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity).

Comment: The rod experiences tension from the "dark energy", but the amount of this tension (based on the value of the cosmological constant) would be very small relative to the tensile strength of any reasonable hypothetical rod. The problem with this hypothetical speculation is that it is impossible for such a rod to be created (manufactured).